# Prove: $\operatorname{E}[X^2]<\infty\Longrightarrow \operatorname{E}[X]$ exists

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, expected-value

I don't know how to prove this. Lets assume that $X$ is a discrete random variable. I've just come this far: If we do a direct proof of the implication, then we start with the assumption:
$$
\operatorname{E}[X^2]=\sum_{x\in Im(X)} x^2\cdot p_X(x) <\infty.
$$
However, I don't know how I can follow from this that $\operatorname{E}[X]$ exists.

Comment: With the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, you can prove more: if $X, Y \in \mathcal L^2$, then $XY \in \mathcal L^1$. Yours is the special case $Y=1$

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you post it as an answer in more detail?

Comment: some other answers have been posted in that direction.. Otherwise good old wikipedia is always useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have $|X|\leq1+X^2$ and consequently $$\mathbb E|X|\leq1+\mathbb EX^2$$

So $\mathbb EX^2<\infty$ allows the conclusion that $\mathbb EX$ exists.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: I'm quite impressed how many topics are touched within this proof: $X\leq Y\Longrightarrow\operatorname{E}[X]\leq\operatorname{E}[Y]$, linearity of expected value, absolute convergence $\Longrightarrow$ convergence.

Comment: @ndrizza Is also useful to keep in mind that absolute convergence $\iff$ convergence :)

Comment: A sidenote: I was hesitating for a moment whether the absolute value for X is needed. But it really is - it avoids the case where $\operatorname{E}[X]$ may tend to minus infinity.

Answer (score 4):

An even more general statement, shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26454/proof-that-if-higher-moment-exists-then-lower-moment-also-exists), is if 
$$
\mathbb E(|X^r|)< \infty
$$
then
for any positive integer $s<r$, the
$s$-th moment $\mathbb E[|X^s|]$ is also finite (and thus $\mathbb E[X^s]$ exists).

This can be done by noticing that
$0<s<r \Longrightarrow |X|^s \le \max(1, |X|^r) $.

Comment: Thanks. Also very useful to know it in a more general context.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of Jenson's inequality for probability measures, for $f(x)=x^r$ with $r\geq 1$, implies:

$$f(E[X]])\leq E[f(X)],$$

which gives, after rearranging:

$$E[X]\leq E[X^r]^{1/r}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's another; Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

$$E|X| = E|X|\cdot 1 \le \|1\|_2 \|X\|_2 = \left(E|X|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$